# How can I add a FirebaseUser profile update to a batched write with Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to perform a batched write with Cloud Firestore. When the batched write is performed, it will update the user's document in the database with the link to the new profile image that the user has selected. I also want to perform this update directly to the FirebaseUser using `UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()`. Is there some way I can add the FirebaseUser update to the batched write so that the two updates happen simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to turn multiple operations among multiple products into a single atomic operation.  You will have to perform and check the result of each on independently, and undo any prior changes if there are problems.  I suggest doing the reversible option (database write) first.  Or simply ignore the Firebase Auth profile information, since it's not really necessary for anything while you have the database available.